# Collect the values of a Map into a MapSet

Tags: elixir

```
# Collect the values of a map into a mapset
def values(map) do
    Enum.reduce(map, MapSet.new(),  
        fn ({_, value}, acc) -> 
            MapSet.put(acc, value) 
        end 
    ) 
end 

values.(%{"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}) |>
IO.inspect
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this values function?

Comment: Does the `Map` provide access to its values as a collection? In Java I would express this as `new Set(map.values())`, using the Set constructor that copies elements from another collection.

Comment: After reading the documentation, `MapSet.new(map.values())` is probably all you need.